# Module Federation - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' Angular 13 while consuming MFE

Tags: angular, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I am trying to consume an MFE using webpack 5, module federation with angular 13. However when I run the application I am getting below error.

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'**

Error occurring with the below code in webpack.config

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "shell",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",           
      remotes: {
                MfeAccount: "https://account-mfexyz.com/remoteEntry.js"
              },
})
```

To me everything looks good, but still application not able to access remote MFE, and throwing error.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

While mentioning remotes in ModuleFederationPlugin, You do not have to mention name and filename. Put like this:

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({          
  remotes: {
            MfeAccount: "https://account-mfexyz.com/remoteEntry.js"
          },
```

})